# Recursion using C language

Tags: c, recursion

When I compile this program I only get the first capital letter but not the rest.

#### Input:

> ABldjfdslkjfCK

I only get 'A' that is it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
FILE *fp;

int main(void)
{   
    int size; 
    char input[100]; // array size of 100 
         
    if (fp = fopen("message.txt","r")) // file exists
    {
        fgets(input,100,fp);// scans the sentence. 
    }
    else 
    {
    printf("file not found");// if there is no such a file. 
    }    

    size=strlen(input);  
    recursive(size,input); 
         
    return 0;
}

int recursive(int size, char array[])
{
    static int index = 0; // static so when the function is called, the  value is kept

    if (index < size) // start from index 0 until the size-1
    {
        if (array[index] >= 'A' && array[index] <= 'Z') // check for A to Z  (CAPITALIZE CHARACTERS only)
        {
            printf("%c\n", array[index]); // print it
        }
        else 
        {
            return recursive(size,array); // calls the function (recursion)
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not have a global FILE*.  You should declare it in main().

Comment: `fgets(input,100,fp)` -> `fgets(input,sizeof(input),fp)`

Comment: Use 'isupper()' from `<ctype.h>` to detect upper-case letters.

Comment: You really should not be using a static variable 'index' in a recursive function; unless you are extremely careful, it means you can only use the function once (because if it is not zeroed when the function exits from the call stack, all hell is likely to break loose, especially if the previous line was long and the current line is short, and they don't share the same input buffer).  [After reading more answers, I see Michael Burr also noted this problem.]

Comment: An additional problem is that if you fail to open the file, you still try to process the string which was not explicitly initialized by reading any data into it - which can lead to trouble.  The 'strlen()' and 'recursive()' functions (and fclose() - its absence is another problem) should be in the 'if' clause.  I would also argue that errors should be written to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: Speaking of errors, it's possible to fail to open the file for other reasons too, e.g. insufficient permissions or an I/O error (broken disk). To make the program more explicit the `perror` function could be used, for example like this: `perror("failed to open file")`. On BSD compatible system including Linux (`gcc -D_BSD_SOURCE`), you can also use `void err(int eval, const char *fmt, ...);` from `err.h`.

Comment: I believe you need to learn some debugging techniques in order to be able to identify problems in your code. 
I am not trying to be smart, but the issues regarding why your recursion isnt working are quite elementary and can be easily identified by using some debugging techniques.
You could use a debugger such as gdb, or one built in to your IDE like in Eclipse or Visual Studio. 
Next time: try inserting some debug print messages or even walk through the code visually before compilation

Answer (score 14):

You never increment the value of `index`.  Furthermore, you do not call the function `recursive` if the current character is a capital letter, so the function just returns.

Rather than using a static variable for `index`, it would be better to pass it in as an argument to `recursive`; otherwise, the function is non-reentrant.

Comment: Reentrant - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29 (for anyone who doesn't remember what it means, like me :)

Answer (score 4):

your recursive function calls to itself only if it finds a non capital character. when it finds the first capital character it prints it and quits

Answer (score 3):

Your current function prints only `A` because as soon as it finds an uppercase letter (`A` in your case) it returns a 0.

There are other issues too, so I would rewrite the function like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>  /* for isupper */

void recursive(const char* s)
{
    /* stop condition: empty string */
    if (s[0] == '\0')
        return;
    /* main body: print letter if capital */
    if (isupper(s[0]))
        printf("%c\n", s[0]);
    /* recursion: advance to the next character */
    recursive(s + 1);
}
```

Use it like this: `recursive(input)`.

Comment: Of course, this is an example of tail recursion, which is trivially removed by using a while loop instead - but you've captured the intent rather clearly (and the basic rule of successful recursion: know when to stop and when to continue).

Answer (score 3):

Among the other issues that your recursive function has is that the `index` variable is static. That's not a problem in the current versions, since you don't actually use it except in a trivial way. But once you try to fix the other problems (which may result in you using `index` in s more complicated way), having it `static` will pose a couple problems:

- there's no good way to initialize it properly after the first use.  This is often fixed by having a non-recursive 'wrapper' function that initializes the state variable and passes it to a private recursive function that does the actual work (and takes the value as a parameter instead of using a static instance).  The wrapper just kicks off the function that does the real work.
- the recursive calls to the function will modify the static variable, which will modify the state of the 'saved' instance of the in progress recursive calls.  This might not be a problem if the recursion is a type known as 'tail recursion' where the caller that performs the recursive call won't perform any additional work after the recursive call returns, but not all recursive functions are tail recursion. Though your example could easily be (I'd still try to avoid the static variable, though).

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You are terminating your recursion incorrectly.  You need to keep recursing until you reach the end of the array.
2. You have a second problem where you are not incrementing index so each call will always look at the first character.

Answer (score 1):

The first error I see is that you never increment index.